Global axes in rotations with quaternions in three
I call this function every frame sending it 3 angles. The X and Y axes rotate in global axes but X rotates in the local X axis of the object. Everything works fine but the problem is that X rotates on the local axis.
The code of the entire application is very extensive. What I’m doing is creating a system that saves the total rotations of objects in degrees. For example, an object may have a cumulative rotation of (967,892,-450). I then interpolate these values ​​and call the function that performs the rotation.Can someone help me get the 3 axes to rotate in global axes? Thanks!
const lerpRotation = {
    x: { total: THREE.MathUtils.lerp(prevKeyframe.userDataRotation.x.total, nextKeyframe.userDataRotation.x.total, interpolatedT) },
    y: { total: THREE.MathUtils.lerp(prevKeyframe.userDataRotation.y.total, nextKeyframe.userDataRotation.y.total, interpolatedT) },
    z: { total: THREE.MathUtils.lerp(prevKeyframe.userDataRotation.z.total, nextKeyframe.userDataRotation.z.total, interpolatedT) }
};


         setObjectRotation(object, {
                x: lerpRotation.x.total,
                y: lerpRotation.y.total,
                z: lerpRotation.z.total
            });


function setObjectRotation(object, rotationAngles) {
    const xRad = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(rotationAngles.x);
    const yRad = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(rotationAngles.y);
    const zRad = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(rotationAngles.z);

    // Reset the object's quaternion to identity
    object.quaternion.identity();

      
      const xAxis = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
      const yAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
      const zAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);


 
    
    // Create quaternions for each axis
    const qx = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(xAxis, xRad);
    const qy = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(yAxis, yRad);
    const qz = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(zAxis, zRad);
   
    // Combine the quaternions in the correct order for global rotation
    object.quaternion.multiply(qz); // X rotation first
    object.quaternion.multiply(qy); // Y rotation second

    object.quaternion.multiply(qx); // Z rotation last
    
  
    object.updateMatrix();
    object.updateMatrixWorld();

 
 } 

